# IIS failed request log viewer

Tags: iis, iis-7

It's there an existing application to visualize IIS 7.0 failed request log ?

I know you can use IE to analyse the xml log file, and we get a visual generate by the xsl file, but my xml log file have 97 MO and the IE performance is not got.

I cannot view the performance log, because i beleive there a javascript error generated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i create my own parser.

I create a little software, who read log, and show the lines who take the biggest time to be executed.

Very useful to optimse old asp.

If some people need it, just tell me and i will put the source.

There is the [solutions](http://www.onedollarpub.com/download/IISLogReader.rar), give me some feed back. I do it very quickly so, could be some error.